Decrypt AES file in Flutter
I try to encrypt a file in php, then decrypt it in a flutter app
I encrypt file in php with the following code :
$this->key = hash('sha256', $formationPurchased['encryption_key'], true);
$this->iv = substr(hash('sha256', "16charstring", true), 0, 16);
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($content, 'aes-256-cbc', $this->key, 0, $this->iv);
file_put_contents($tmp_file, $encrypted);

This file is directly downloaded in the browser.
I wan't to decrypt this file via a Flutter App (desktop, MacOs during debug, but have to be compatible with Windows), I actually have this code :
final fileBytes = await File('$filePath').readAsBytes();

var mykey = support['encryptionKey'];
var myiv = '16charstring';

final keyString = Uint8List.fromList(sha256.convert(utf8.encode(mykey)).bytes);
final ivString = Uint8List.fromList(sha256.convert(utf8.encode(myiv)).bytes.sublist(0, 16));

var iv = encrypt.IV(ivString);

var encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(encrypt.Key(keyString), mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc));

final encrypted = encrypt.Encrypted(fileBytes);
final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
return decrypted;

But the encrypter.decrypt give me the following error :
Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block
I don't understand why, I've tried a lot of things, but I can't decrypt the files...

PHP/OpenSSL encodes the ciphertext with Base64 by default. In the Dart code the Base64 decoding seems to be missing (or try Encrypted.fromBase64()). If it still does not work, post sample data: key, IV, (small) plaintext, ciphertext.
